# Flask - Getting POST data from Angular $http.post()

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, post, flask

In a very basic test web app I am making, I am using angular to run a function when a form is submitted. The function asynchronously posts data to a simple api I built which is supposed to input data into a database dependent on the POST information it receives. It seems like the POST is working correctly on the front end, however I cannot access `request.json` from Flask at all or get any of the post data. I feel like this problem may be something simple I have overlooked but as of now I cannot figure it out at all. Here is some of the code:

AngularJS:

```
$scope.submitAddMsg = function (){
        var data = {'author': $scope.msgauthor, 'message': $scope.msgmsg};
        $http.post('/addMessage', data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    };
```

Flask view function for `/addMessage`

```
@app.route('/addMessage', methods=['POST'])
def addMessage():
    #results in 'None type not iterable'
    #response = request.form.get('author')

    #results in a 400 error
    #response = request.get_json()

    #results in a 400 error
    #response = request.get_json()

    #results in 'author' not defined
    #name = request.args.get('author')
    #return jsonify(author = author)

    return str(jsonify(response))
```

I cannot stop getting errors as if the request is not what I think it should be, is there something else I should be doing to properly handle this? Because I cannot access any POST information when using Angular to send the POST or even a REST Client with payload exactly how the angular is sending data.

Here is the JavaScript console to see what `data`, `status`, `headers`, and `config` ends up being in the success function that runs after the POST:

```
<Response 46 bytes [200 OK]>
testbase.js:53 200
testbase.js:54 function (c){a||(a=Xc(b));return c?(c=a[z(c)],void 0===c&&    (c=null),c):a}
testbase.js:55 Object {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array[1],     transformResponse: Array[1], headers: Object, url: "/addMessage"…}data:     Objectheaders: ObjectAccept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"Content-Type:     "application/json"__proto__: Objectmethod: "POST"transformRequest:     Array[1]transformResponse: Array[1]url: "/addMessage"__proto__: Object
```

Any help on getting this working right is much appreciated, let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

you can use `request.data` to get the raw post data.

you can also set the `silent` Flag of `get_json` to `True` so you can get the exact message of failure.

from the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data)

> get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)
>
> Parameters:
>      force – if set to True the mimetype is ignored.
>      silent – if set to False this method will fail silently and return False.
>      cache – if set to True the parsed JSON data is remembered on the request.

Comment: I tried this as well (forgot to write it above) and believe got another 400 error, I can double check though, if none of these are working properly something small must be off, I don't get why `requests` is not what I'm expecting it to be, it is being imported too btw

Comment: you can hand code a simple json (even an empty json ) and try to read it back in flask, to see if it really is problem with the data that is being passed, or you can remove the header from $http.post() and let flask guess the mimetype.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried those and they result in similar failures. It seems that whenever trying to access anything that would normally exist inside the request object, nothing exists and it results in a 400 error. I am not sure if Flask is handling the request incorrectly or something like that, when I get in front of my code I can try a couple of other things but the request object is basically not what it should be I believe

Comment: Ok @Anbarasan , so in flask when i `return str(type(request.data))` I get <class 'bytes'>, shouldn't it be text or json so that I can use it as a dictionary?

Comment: But if I just return request.data or request.get_data() Javascript logs in the console the correct data so I know its being passed correctly, but for whatever reason it is of type bytes when Python gets it is unusable

Comment: try to do a try except and print the exact error to logs that is causing the 400 bad request.  
from what i have seen, 400 error happens when we try to access something which is not available in request.  usually a Key Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `app.debug = True` before you start the app and try again.

You can also try: 
message = request.json.get('message')

And I would also try putting this in your route

['POST', 'OPTIONS'])